# Problem uploading images with Axios and Laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

I'm trying to upload and save images with Axios and a Laravel API, but i'm getting a 422 error.

I've tested with Postman and i have the same result, i have a similar controller**(without the Foreach)** but to upload only one image at once and it works fine.

```
///Axios

    async submitFiles(){
       let fd = new FormData()
       for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
         let file = this.files[i]
         fd.append('photo[' + i + ']', file)
       }
       try{
        await this.$axios.$post(`/albums/${this.$route.params.id}/photos`, fd, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
        console.log(...fd)
        alert('uploaded')
        this.files = []
      }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        alert(err)
      }

     }
```

```
//Laravel

class PhotosInAlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function store(PhotoInAlbumRequest $request, Album $album)
    {


        if($request->hasfile('photo')) 
        {

            $photo = new PhotoInAlbum();
            $photo->photo = $request->photo;
            $images[] = $request->file('photo');
            foreach ($images as $image) 
            {
                $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = pathInfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $path = $image->storeAs('photo/images', $filenameToStore,'public');
                $photo->photo = $path;
                $album->photos()->save($photo);

            }

        }

        return $photo;

    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me to figure out what's going on.

Thanks in advance (=

Comment: 422 often means a validation error. What are your validation rules?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, my rules are just to check if im actually uploading an image (jpeg,png) that's all =O

Comment: Can you put `console.log(err.response.data)` in the `catch` part of your javascript and post the contents here?

Comment: Sure, this is what i get: VM101:1 POST http://-----/api/albums/15/photos 422 (Unprocessable Entity)  

And 

Error: Request failed with status code 422

Comment: @Mario I am making some assumption because you haven't shared your PhotoInAlbumRequest class, but I think I recently ran into this issue myself. It looks like photo is an array and photo.* needs to use the image validation rule. Could you confirm this by checking the PhotoInAlbumRequest or sharing it here by updating your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry I can't comment yet. But I see in this line: 
  $images[] = $request->file('photo'); 
that a bi-dimensional array is built. I would try the assignment without the brackets:
   $images = $request->file('photo');

Comment: Hi Juan, i have $images[] because if i use only $images, it stores me .temp files instead of images idk why =O

Comment: Hi Mario, and if you try foreach($images[0] as $image) ?

Comment: The same, no difference

Comment: also I see that you receive in laravel function a type Album param and pass through axios an id. Don't you miss an Album::find($album) call?